# Uniform convergence on a sequence

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, continuity

If a sequence of functions $f_n$ is continuous, and $f$ is also continuous on its domain, does this imply uniform convergence? I think it should, but does anyone know of a good counterexample?

Comment: Why is no answer accepted?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Consider
$$f_n(x) = (x + \tfrac{1}{n})^2$$
on $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

Take $f:\Bbb R\longrightarrow\Bbb R$ continuous, with bounded support and  $\ne 0$. The sequence $(f_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ defined by $f_n(x) = f(x - n)$ is a counterexample because $(f_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}\to 0$ pointwise but
$$\forall n\in \Bbb N:\ \|f_n - 0\| =\|f\|\ne 0.$$
($\|\ \| = \sup$ norm)

Answer (score 0):

The sequence $f_n(x)=\frac{x}{n}$ converges pointwise to the continuous function $f(x)=0$ but the convergence is not uniform on $\mathbb R$.